# SQL Paging - Search the OFFSET value to get a specific page

Tags: sql

I have a problem with pagination. Using MYSQL, MariaDB and PostgreSQL. I am looking for a solution **without** vendor specific functions like ROW_NUMBER().

I have a (simplified) table as shown. I want to retrieve a page with 10 Rows containing a given id value.

```
SELECT id, costcentre_id, costcentreuser_id, createdate FROM devices
   WHERE id < 62 ORDER BY createdate DESC;
+----+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id | costcentre_id | costcentreuser_id | createdate          |
+----+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 61 |            18 |                31 | 2015-07-13 13:54:06 |+++++++
| 55 |            13 |                28 | 2015-07-13 13:54:05 |
| 53 |            16 |                27 | 2015-07-13 13:54:05 |
| 54 |            16 |                27 | 2015-07-13 13:54:05 |
| 56 |            13 |                28 | 2015-07-13 13:54:05 | Page 1
| 57 |             5 |                29 | 2015-07-13 13:54:05 |
| 58 |             5 |                29 | 2015-07-13 13:54:05 |
| 59 |            17 |                30 | 2015-07-13 13:54:05 |
| 60 |            17 |                30 | 2015-07-13 13:54:05 |
| 46 |             5 |                23 | 2015-07-13 13:54:04 |
| 45 |             5 |                23 | 2015-07-13 13:54:04 |+++++++
| 47 |            13 |                24 | 2015-07-13 13:54:04 |
| 48 |            13 |                24 | 2015-07-13 13:54:04 |
| 49 |            14 |                25 | 2015-07-13 13:54:04 |
| 50 |            14 |                25 | 2015-07-13 13:54:04 |
| 51 |            15 |                26 | 2015-07-13 13:54:04 | Page 2
| 52 |            15 |                26 | 2015-07-13 13:54:04 |
| 37 |             5 |                19 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 38 |             5 |                19 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 39 |            12 |                20 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 40 |            12 |                20 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |+++++++
| 41 |             5 |                21 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 42 |             5 |                21 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 43 |            11 |                22 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 44 |            11 |                22 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 36 |            11 |                18 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 | Page 3
| 35 |**          11 |                18 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
| 34 |             6 |                17 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
| 33 |             6 |                17 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
| 32 |             5 |                16 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
| 31 |             5 |                16 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |+++++++
| 30 |             5 |                15 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
| 29 |             5 |                15 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
| 21 |             5 |                11 | 2015-07-13 13:54:01 |
| 22 |             5 |                11 | 2015-07-13 13:54:01 |
| 23 |             5 |                12 | 2015-07-13 13:54:01 | Page 4
| 24 |             5 |                12 | 2015-07-13 13:54:01 |
| 25 |             5 |                13 | 2015-07-13 13:54:01 |
| 26 |             5 |                13 | 2015-07-13 13:54:01 |
| 27 |            10 |                14 | 2015-07-13 13:54:01 |
| 28 |            10 |                14 | 2015-07-13 13:54:01 |+++++++
| 11 |             6 |                 6 | 2015-07-13 13:54:00 |
| 12 |             6 |                 6 | 2015-07-13 13:54:00 |
| 13 |             7 |                 7 | 2015-07-13 13:54:00 |
| 14 |             7 |                 7 | 2015-07-13 13:54:00 |
| 15 |             5 |                 8 | 2015-07-13 13:54:00 |
| 16 |             5 |                 8 | 2015-07-13 13:54:00 |
| 17 |             8 |                 9 | 2015-07-13 13:54:00 |
| 18 |             8 |                 9 | 2015-07-13 13:54:00 |
| 19 |             9 |                10 | 2015-07-13 13:54:00 |
| 20 |             9 |                10 | 2015-07-13 13:54:00 |
|  2 |             1 |                 1 | 2015-07-13 13:53:59 |
|  3 |             2 |                 2 | 2015-07-13 13:53:59 |
|  4 |             2 |                 2 | 2015-07-13 13:53:59 |
|  5 |             3 |                 3 | 2015-07-13 13:53:59 |
|  6 |             3 |                 3 | 2015-07-13 13:53:59 |
|  7 |             4 |                 4 | 2015-07-13 13:53:59 |
|  8 |             4 |                 4 | 2015-07-13 13:53:59 |
|  9 |             5 |                 5 | 2015-07-13 13:53:59 |
| 10 |             5 |                 5 | 2015-07-13 13:53:59 |
|  1 |             1 |                 1 | 2015-07-13 13:53:59 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

I want to get the page with id 35 (here page 3)

```
SELECT id, costcentre_id, costcentreuser_id, createdate FROM devices
   WHERE id < 62 ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20;
+----+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id | costcentre_id | costcentreuser_id | createdate          |
+----+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 37 |             5 |                19 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 40 |            12 |                20 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 41 |             5 |                21 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 38 |             5 |                19 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 42 |             5 |                21 | 2015-07-13 13:54:03 |
| 35 |**          11 |                18 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
| 36 |            11 |                18 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
| 33 |             6 |                17 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
| 29 |             5 |                15 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
| 30 |             5 |                15 | 2015-07-13 13:54:02 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

But how to calculate the OFFSET value automatically?

Thank you for any idea!

Comment: I don't see any basic SQL solution without a defined row order. If you don't specify any order the results will always be undefined.

Comment: If, however, you do have a defined order, say on the (unique) createdate, you can simply `select count(*)/10 as PageNo from devices d1 inner join devices d2 on d1.createdate > d2.createdate where d2.id = 35 and ...`.

Comment: do you have a client language that is working with this, or does it have to be a complete self-contained SQL solution. Does it have to work with ALL of the above mentioned databases, or only with ANY?

Comment: ALL or ANY? It is possible, that the database will be changed - but nobody want to search for specific SQL. The above is a snippet from an ERP software.

Comment: Hi Hanno, your tipp looks interesting - but I did not get it in a runnable form... The only unique value is the column "id".

Answer (score 0):

You can use TOP to your advantage here. Some DBMSs support a variable or dynamic TOP condition, but if not, this would need to be generated in your target language.

This is also not the most efficient way, but only depends on whether you can have a deterministic sorting key.

```
--offset 10, page 2
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10 * --top offset number
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 20 * --top offset * page number
        FROM MyTable
        ORDER BY id --sort ASCENDING
        ) T1
    ORDER BY id DESC --sort by same key DESCENDING
    ) T2
ORDER BY id --reorder to original order, unless you want to order in client app
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks line *none* of the RDBMSs the OP named understand the `TOP` syntax.